# how to add bottom floated non-menu content to semantic-ui menu

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

i am using semantic-ui (via react-semantic-ui).  i want a little area for logon in the bottom of my menu column.

i have this:

[image]

i want this:

[image]

i did the above using `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, but i'm betting there's a semantic positioning class or `react-semantic-ui` component to use that would achieve it w/out manual styles

my components are as follows:

```
  <Menu vertical fixed={'left'} inverted>
    <Menu.Item name='account' active />
    <Menu.Item name='settings' active={false} />
    <Menu.Menu>
      <img width="50px" height="50px" style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} />
      <Menu.Item name='logout' active={false} onClick={() => null} />
    </Menu.Menu>
  </Menu>
```

Comment: Semantic UI has 'bottom aligned content' class, It should do what you're trying to. http://semantic-ui.com/views/item.html

Comment: hey @IlanHasanov, thanks for the info.  I'm having a difficult time implementing it.  In your link, everything is wrapped in an `items` group.  The items group, however, does not vertically expand to fill the space, therefore my little red-box node is stuck.  further, the verticalAlign seems to be for content within an item, not for an item within an item group.  any thoughts there?  thanks!

Comment: use custom css then..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Segment element](http://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/segment). The `attached` prop is what you'll find most useful and you can easily customize it to become a full menu.

```
<Segment attached='bottom'></Segment>
```

You should easily be able to cusomize this to fit your stylistic needs.

Comment: hey Chase! thanks for the tip! `Segment` adds a nice little wrapper around the card I was using--thx! Unfortunately, attached='bottom' doesn't actually drop it to the bottom of the menu. here's a [live example](https://cdaringe.github.io/octagon/?selectedKind=core.Menu&selectedStory=vertical%20w%2F%20bottom%20content&full=0&down=1&left=1&panelRight=0&downPanel=kadirahq%2Fstorybook-addon-actions%2Factions-panel): , [here's the source](https://github.com/cdaringe/octagon/blob/master/src/menu/Menu.stories.js#L22) for that example